# How to fix the order in which text appears in an axis label (V7)

Tags: plotting, labeling, version-7

[image]

One of the AxesLabel is "$:\text{log}|\Phi8b(u)|\color{Red}{\text{Red}}$".

Question: How to make it like: "$\color{Red}{\text{Red}}:\text{log}|\Phi8b(u)|$"?.

My *Mathematica* commads:

```
Φ8[u_] := Sin[u]; 

Φ8b[u_] := Sin[u] + 1/10; 

Plot[{Log[Abs[Φ8[u]]], Log[Abs[Φ8b[u]]]}, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red, Dashed}}, 
  AxesLabel -> 
    {u, {Style["Blue", {Blue, Bold}]*":log|Φ8(u)|", 
         Style["Red",  {Red, Bold}]*" :log|Φ8b(u)|"}}]
```

Comment: Can you post the code as copy-paste-ble text. It would be easier to handle.

Comment: @MatsGranvik  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: This would be better suited at Mathematica.SE.

Comment: Yes. But I was not able to post it at Mathematica site, as I mentioned above.  Could someone help me to move it to Mathematica site?

Comment: Try imposing order on your label (e.g. using `Row`): `Row[{Style["Red", {Red, Bold}], ": log|f(u)|"}]`. As it is, *Mathematica* reorders your expression by default.

Comment: As nobody has mentioned the elephant in the room, I will. You have expressed your label text as a multiplication and _Mathematica_ is doing its normal lexical reordering on it.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I was not able to create a Mathematica.SE account with my PC because it failed to load a Java script. But I was able to do it with my cell phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[{Log[Abs[\[CapitalPhi]8[u]]], Log[Abs[\[CapitalPhi]8b[u]]]}, {u, 0, 2*Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red, Dashed}},
 AxesLabel -> Row[{
    Style["Blue", {Blue, Bold}], ":log|\[CapitalPhi]8(u)|",
    Style["  Red", {Red, Bold}], ":log|\[CapitalPhi]8b(u)|"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked with Mathematica V7.0.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the ultimate aim is but for motivation:

```
p = Plot[{Log[Abs[\[CapitalPhi]8[u]]], 
    Log[Abs[\[CapitalPhi]8b[u]]]}, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Red, Dashed}}, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]];
rp = ReplacePart[
  p, {2, 1, 2} -> 
   Inner[Style[#1, #2] &, p[[2, 1, 2]], {Blue, Red}, List]]
```

[image]

Comment: Will this work with V7?

Comment: @YvesKlett doh...was too focused on changing `LabelStyle` completely missed the point...v7...in short NO...perhaps will motivate similar 'looking under hood':)

Comment: Eek... the old legends package was not all that easy to work with :D

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But it did not work for V7.  Thanks a lot!